# using useStates in js react how to display one div at a time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, styled-components, use-state

I have 3 divs and 3 buttons that were created through styled components is react js, and I want to know how to display one div by default when the page loads, and when the user clicks the other two buttons I want that div to display and the other divs to disappear using useStates.

this is what I thought of doing creating useState and a function with a parameter of "displayDiv"
and maybe pass the selected div as a argument through a click of one of the buttons, but I don't know how to go about doing it.

```
const Maincontainer = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid black;
`
const Divbtncontainer = styled.div`
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
`
const Div1btn = styled.button`
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    width: 15%;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        background: #1B1212;
        color: cyan;
        transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
    }
`
const Div2btn = styled.button`
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    width: 15%;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        background: #1B1212;
        color: cyan;
        transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
    }
`
const Div3btn = styled.button`
    border-radius: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background: #D3D3D3;
    width: 15%;
    cursor: pointer;
    &:hover{
        background: #1B1212;
        color: cyan;
        transition: ease-in-out 0.3s;
    }
`
const Divscontainer = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;

`
const Div1 = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
`
const Div2 = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
`
const Div3 = styled.div`
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid black;
`


    function App() {
     const [visableDiv, setVisableDiv] = useState();   
            function setDivToVisable(displayDiv){
                setVisableDiv(displayDiv)
            }
                  <Maincontainer>
                    <Divbtncontainer>
                        <Div1btn>
                            Div 1
                        </Div1btn>
                        <Div2btn>
                            Div 2
                        </Div2btn>
                        <Div3btn>
                            Div 3
                        </Div3btn>
                    </Divbtncontainer>
                    <Divscontainer>
                        <Div1>
                            <h2>This is div 1 </h2>
                        </Div1>
                        <Div2>
                            <h2>This is div 2 </h2>
                        </Div2>
                        <Div3>
                            <h2>This is div 3 </h2>
                        </Div3>
                    </Divscontainer>
                </Maincontainer>
    
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried conditional rendering of the selected div? Can you provide a more complete/comprehensive code example for what you've tried?

Comment: Here's how to do this properly, without duplicate code: https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-microservice-dqtdw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 3):

You can manage using conditional rendering.

```
 function App() {
  const [visableDiv, setVisableDiv] = useState("Div 1");

  const setDivToVisable = (displayDiv) => {
    setVisableDiv(displayDiv);
  };

  <Maincontainer>
    <Divbtncontainer>
      <Div1btn onClick={() => setDivToVisable('Div 1')}>Div 1</Div1btn>
      <Div2btn onClick={() => setDivToVisable('Div 2')}>Div 2</Div2btn>
      <Div3btn onClick={() => setDivToVisable('Div 3')}>Div 3</Div3btn>
    </Divbtncontainer>
    <Divscontainer>
      {visableDiv === "Div 1" && (
        <Div1>
          <h2>This is div 1 </h2>
        </Div1>
      )}
      {visableDiv === "Div 2" && (
        <Div2>
          <h2>This is Div 2 </h2>
        </Div2>
      )}
      {visableDiv === "Div 3" && (
        <Div3>
          <h2>This is div 3 </h2>
        </Div3>
      )}
    </Divscontainer>
  </Maincontainer>;
}
```

Comment: This solution does not adhere to the DRY principle; OP has lots of duplicate code that should be eliminated. And adding a forth div requires copy-pasting a section which again, is bad practice.

Comment: Agreed, Lots of code are duplicate need to refactor batter way as you mention in your comment https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-microservice-dqtdw?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

no duplicate code and you can add as many divs as you like:

```
import {useState } from 'react'
const divs = [
  <div>
      <h2>This is div 1 </h2>
  </div>,
  <div>
      <h2>This is div 2 </h2>
  </div>,
  <div>
      <h2>This is div 3 </h2>
  </div>,
];
export const App= () => {
  const [visibleDivIndex, setVisibleDivIndex] = useState(0);

  return (
      <div>
          <div id="container">
              {divs.map((_, index) => (
                  <button onClick={() => setVisibleDivIndex(index)}>
                      Div {index + 1}
                  </button>
              ))}
          </div>
          <div>{divs[visibleDivIndex]}</div>
      </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can place the divs into an array, render the div at the selected index (defaulting to `0`), then change the index when a button is clicked.

```
const elements = [
    <Div1>
        <h2>This is div 1 </h2>
    </Div1>,
    <Div2>
        <h2>This is div 2 </h2>
    </Div2>,
    <Div3>
        <h2>This is div 3 </h2>
    </Div3>,
];

function App() {
    const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

    function clickHandler(index) {
        return () => setIndex(index);
    }

    return (
        <Maincontainer>
            <Divbtncontainer>
                <Div1btn onClick={clickHandler(0)}>
                    Div 1
                </Div1btn>
                <Div2btn onClick={clickHandler(1)}>
                    Div 2
                </Div2btn>
                <Div3btn onClick={clickHandler(2)}>
                    Div 3
                </Div3btn>
            </Divbtncontainer>
            <Divscontainer>
                {elements[index]}
            </Divscontainer>
        </Maincontainer>
    );
}
```

There are better and more scalable ways to do this kind of thing, but they don't quite fit your example as you're using unique components at every position. I'm not sure why `Div2btn`, `Div3Btn`, `Div2` and `Div3` exist when they're the same as `Div1btn` and `Div1`.